# how to create multiple textview with different id and different name android?

Tags: android

how to create multiple textviews (Say 4) dynamically in some layout and have different names and id for them ,sothat we can have on click listener to them and perform different operatins on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instance of `TextView` in a loop and add listener to them in loop itself. You can set id using `setId()` method and Text using `setText()`.

```
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {   
    TextView txt = new TextView(context);  
    txt.setId(i);   txt.setText("Button "+i);  
    txt.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  System.out.println("Button "+i+"Clicked!");
              }
          });
    layout.addView(txt);  
}
```

In onClick method you can check for id of v and using if-else loop, you can provide different functionality for each click.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the textView which u are adding in a ArrayList side by side and add a position tag with it as well, according to the size of the arraylist
like this.

```
  arrayList.add(textView);
  textView.setTag(arraylist.size());
```

Then onClickListener you can get the tag doing

```
  onClick(View view){
  if (view == arraylist.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag()))){
  // do onClick coding here
  }
  }
```

and use that tag to implement different clickListenrs.